# How i fix first row data constant based on a condition and sort rest of data in datagrid according to date?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I want to fix first row data in datagrid according to a coloumn Status, if data status is new then it should be on index 0 first row, and sort other datagrid rows based on the date coloumn.
i already sorted all data on the base of a single coloum like date. i also tried to sort with the given function but it's not working fine.

```
public static function sortDataGridMultiColumn(columnOne: String, columnTwo: String, decending: Boolean, array: ArrayCollection): void {

   var sortThese: Sort = new Sort();
   sortThese.fields = [new SortField(columnOne, false, decending),
   new SortField(columnTwo, false, decending)];
   array.sort = sortThese;
   array.refresh();

}
```

Comment: Thanks, resolved by myself.

Comment: Could you please post the solution you found as an answer and mark it as accepted? That will show people that the problem is resolved, and could also help anyone else with a similar problem.

Comment: thanks for guiding. i posted my solution. but i doun know how to mark it.

Comment: Below the rating (on the left side of the answer), there should be an outline of a tick mark. Click on that and it will turn green, which indicates that you've accepted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first i sort data in data grid through this function

```
public static function sortDataGrid(columnId:String , decending:Boolean , array:ArrayCollection):void
        {

            var sortThese:Sort = new Sort();            
            sortThese.fields = [new SortField(columnId, false, decending)];
            array.sort = sortThese;             
            array.refresh();    
        }
```

then i Use this function for manually setting the required data on the first index.

```
 public static function sortingNWFDataGrid(arrayCol:ArrayCollection):void 
            {
                var currentIndx:Number = 0;
                for(var i:int = 0 ; i < arrayCol.length; i++){
                    if(arrayCol.getItemAt(i).statusId == UserStatusConstants.NEW_STATUS_ID){
                        currentIndx = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                var newObj:Object = new Object();
                newObj = arrayCol.getItemAt(currentIndx) as Object;
                arrayCol.removeItemAt(currentIndx);
                arrayCol.refresh();
                arrayCol.addItemAt(newObj, 0);
                arrayCol.refresh();
            }
```

any one with better solution or with different approach please provide here.